# Correct \newgeometry retaining preamble settings

Tags: margins, geometry

I am writing a 350-400 page document using the report document class. The entire document uses the oneside flag as per regulations however I need the document to switch to twoside at a certain point. Mainly at the introduction of appendices.

I am using `\newgeometry`; however as per the doc this removes all geometry formatting used in the preamble. I would like to keep all margin definitions or settings such as `headheight` or `headsep` and simply switch to `twoside`.

I have just tried

```
\newgeometry{a4paper,
 twoside,
 top=20mm,
 inner=40mm,
 outer=25mm,
 bottom=40mm,
 headheight=15pt,
 headsep=5mm,
 footnotesep=5mm,
 footskip=20mm - 1em}
```

This correctly switched to two side however it destroyed setting such as `openright` which I can only set in the preamble.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering for the solution for this, just put `oneside,openright` in the `documentclass`. Then later switch to `twoside` as you wish using `\newgeometry`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,british,english,oneside,openright]{report}
```